# Enabling Keepalive on ODBC client for MSSQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, tcp, odbc, keep-alive

I have got step by step information on how to enable/set/modify the keep alive option on MSSQL Server side. But, how to do the same while using ODBC client to connect with MSSQL Server? This is mainly used to close the socket on client side and start reconnecting.

I came across an option called "Connect Timeout
-or-
Connection Timeout", in connection string, which disconnects if there is no connection after that timeout. But i hope TCP keep alive does more than this.

Couple of options would do for me,

1) Is there a keepalive option that could be added in connection string (similar to postgres)?

2) How to get the client socket fd, which connects with the MSSQL Server, (without using OS commands) so that, i could use setsockopt API and enable keep alive

Comment: Read about SQL Server pooling. It may speed up re-connection. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399543(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: My requirement mostly related to disconnecting the TCP after a timeout, instead of waiting infinitely for a response.